# How can I fetch data or records by date column in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, jsp, spring-data-jpa

Actually, I have Orders entity (table) having column and I want to filter the orders data according to createddatetime column. **Basic scenario is, when a user select any date for example: createddate is 03-06-2021 and there are 3-4 records present on that date so it would be able to display total records present on that date from mysql database.**

```
    @Builder.Default
    @Column(updatable=false)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private Date createddatetime=new Date();
```

I have created function in Orders JPA repositiry like this:

```
    List<Orders> findByCreateddatetimeOrderByCreateddatetimeDesc(Date createddate);
```

Below is my API controller code to fetch records on particular date. But on hitting this, I am getting no response (error response).

```
@RequestMapping(value = AkApiUrl.onedayorder, method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<?> onedayorder(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("limit") int limit, @RequestParam("createddate") String createddate ) {
        CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
        int min = limit - 1;
        int max = Constants.limitResult;
        try {
            List<Orders> order = null;
            List<Orders> totalorders = null;
            Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(min, max, Sort.Direction.ASC, "orderid");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date onedayorder = sdf.parse(createddate);
            if(createddate != null && createddate != "") {
                order = ordersdao.findByCreateddatetimeOrderByCreateddatetimeDesc(onedayorder, pageable);
                totalorders = ordersdao.findByCreateddatetimeOrderByCreateddatetimeDesc(onedayorder);
            }else {
                order = ordersdao.findAllByStatus(1, pageable);
                totalorders = ordersdao.findAllByStatus(1);
            }
            if (order != null) {
                CustomResponse.setResponse(order);
                CustomResponse.setMaxlimit(Constants.limitResult);
                CustomResponse.setTotalorders(totalorders.size());
                CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);
                CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CustomResponse.setResponse(null);
            CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
            CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I tried @Query to create custom query using like operator, but again faced type mismatch error. **How can I fix this thing? Any suggestions would be appreciable and valuable.**

[image: Screenshot to show response]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the data is being persisted in a different format than what you are searching by.
you can apply any of the following solutions:

1- make sure that the same date format is used

2- to ignore the time part of the date you can use greater that and pass two dates ,like (createdDate >= 2021-06-14 and createdDate < 2021-06-15)

3- split your search date input and use functions to search like this example

```
@Query("select e from Event e where year(e.eventDate) = ?1 and month(e.eventDate) = ?2")
List<Entity> getByYearAndMonth(int year, int month);
```

Comment: How to handle these things from frontend? As user will be able to see only single date field and need to pass single date in javascript function using Ajax.

Comment: you don't have to do it through the frontend.
You can do the following:
String[] splittedDate = createddate.split("-");
then pass it to the query
ordersdao.findByCreateddatetimeOrderByCreateddatetimeDesc(splittedDate[0],splittedDate[1],splittedDate[2], pageable);
where you query is something like that:
@Query("select e from Event e where year(e.eventDate) = ?1 and month(e.eventDate) = ?2 and day(e.eventDate) = ?3")
List<Entity> getByYearAndMonth(int year, int month,int day);

Comment: So, what to do in javascript function then? I want to fetch records and show that records inside a table. If I select any date from there, then how it would communicate with my backend code.

Comment: quick zoom call?

Comment: Hi, sorry but solution did not worked for me. Is there any other way to search or fetch list of orders by date?

Answer (score 0):

In your Database the date-pattern is "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", so execute a range query like:

```
List<Orders> findByCreateddatetimeBetweenOrderByCreateddatetimeDesc(Date createddateBegin, Date createddateEnd);
```

and give the day, you want from midnight to midnight.

Comment: If I talk about UI part i.e. from frontend there is a single date field. So, how should I handle those things in my Orders JSP page using JavaScript or jQuery with Ajax?

Comment: What do you mean ? You can use the date, you have and in the java-code, you can call date.setHours()

Comment: Please, Do you have any example to show because I did not handle such things before?

Comment: Make Use of Calendar class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
cal.setTime(yourDate);               // sets calendar time/date
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);      // sets hours to 0
cal.getTime();                                       // returns date with hours on 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can solve your problems, but I retrieve data successfully with these code below, hope this could help:)

My `Repository` code, The reason I give this code is that I want you to notice the **parameter type** of `findAllByCreatedDateBetween()` method is `LocalDateTime`:

```java
public interface TemperatureRepository extends CrudRepository<Temperature, Integer> {
    List<Temperature> findAllByCreatedDateBetween(LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime endTime);
}
```

Write you `Controller` code like this:

```java
// Get data on a specific day, e.g., from `2023-04-01 00:00:00` to `2023-04-01 23:59:59`
@GetMapping("/find/temperature/{date}")
    public Iterable<Temperature> findCustomerByCreatedDate(@PathVariable LocalDate date) {
        return tempRepository.findAllByCreatedDateBetween(date.atStartOfDay(),
                date.atTime(23, 59, 59, 999999999));
    }

    @GetMapping("/find/temperature")
    public Iterable<Temperature> findCustomerBetweenDate(@RequestParam LocalDate from, @RequestParam LocalDate to) {
        return tempRepository.findAllByCreatedDateBetween(from.atStartOfDay(),
                to.atTime(23, 59, 59, 999999999));
    }
```

And `http url`:

```
# Get the data on a specific date
GET http://localhost:8080/find/temperature/2023-04-02

# Get the data between two dates
GET http://localhost:8080/find/temperature?from=2023-04-02&to=2023-04-02
```

[image]